# React Native Load JSBundle from Remote Server

Tags: ios, react-native

I Am creating a React Native iOS App where the JSBundle is downloaded from remote server.So far I have done the following steps:-

1. Once App is started i check for the version say for example 1.0 with the remote server where the latest jsbundle is stored.
2. If the version is more then i download the bundle in the background and store in local emulator/phone file system.
3. When i restart the app this latest jsbundle will be loaded.
4. Now my next step is once the latest jsbundle is downloaded i need to immediately refresh the app with the latest bundle.

Kindly help me on this on further details you can refer below git where something similar is done.

[Auto Updater React Native](https://github.com/redbooth/react-native-auto-updater)

Comment: Why don't you just use CodePush ?

Comment: Due to Company internal policies we need to host and use internal Remote Server will code push allow this ?

Comment: u can check this https://github.com/lisong/code-push-server

Comment: @anbuselvan, how's your finding and work so far? I'm looking to explore on this topic too. Appreciate on your comments!